# axis log error with Liferay

Tags: java, logging, liferay, axis

I am trying to implement a salesforce API that uses axis as one of its libraries.  When I deploy the required axis.jar file to the lib/ext dir, I get the following warning on startup, and when the API gets used, it also fails with a "Could not initialize class org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory" runtime error to the screen.

```
Rex 06 Aug 2013 19:55:44,091 WARN  [EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder:184] Factory org.apache.axis.configuration.EngineConfigurationFactoryServlet Ignored: missing required method: public static EngineConfigurationFactory newFactory(Object).
Exception in thread "Thread-12" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
        at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils$2.run(ClassUtils.java:177)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.loadClass(ClassUtils.java:160)
        at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:100)
        at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDTypeMapping.getSerializer(WSDDTypeMapping.java:217)
        at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.deployTypeMapping(WSDDService.java:542)
        at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.initTMR(WSDDService.java:253)
        at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.<init>(WSDDService.java:233)
        at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.<init>(WSDDDeployment.java:192)
        at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDocument.setDocument(WSDDDocument.java:139)
        at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDocument.<init>(WSDDDocument.java:65)
        at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.configureEngine(FileProvider.java:179)
        at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.init(AxisEngine.java:172)
        at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.<init>(AxisEngine.java:156)
        at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.<init>(AxisServer.java:88)
        at org.apache.axis.server.DefaultAxisServerFactory.createServer(DefaultAxisServerFactory.java:109)
        at org.apache.axis.server.DefaultAxisServerFactory.getServer(DefaultAxisServerFactory.java:73)
        at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.getServer(AxisServer.java:73)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.getEngine(AxisServletBase.java:185)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.getOption(AxisServletBase.java:396)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.init(AxisServletBase.java:112)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:156)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
        at com.liferay.util.axis.AxisServlet.doInit(AxisServlet.java:171)
        at com.liferay.util.axis.AxisServlet$InitThread.run(AxisServlet.java:275)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Invalid class loader hierarchy.  You have more than one version of 'org.apache.commons.logging.Log' visible, which is not allowed. (Caused by org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Invalid class loader hierarchy.  You have more than one version of 'org.apache.commons.logging.Log' visible, which is not allowed.) (Caused by org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Invalid class loader hierarchy.  You have more than one version of 'org.apache.commons.logging.Log' visible, which is not allowed. (Caused by org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Invalid class loader hierarchy.  You have more than one version of 'org.apache.commons.logging.Log' visible, which is not allowed.))
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:543)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:235)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:370)
        at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:37)
        at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BaseSerializerFactory.<clinit>(BaseSerializerFactory.java:42)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Invalid class loader hierarchy.  You have more than one version of 'org.apache.commons.logging.Log' visible, which is not allowed. (Caused by org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Invalid class loader hierarchy.  You have more than one version of 'org.apache.commons.logging.Log' visible, which is not allowed.)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getLogConstructor(LogFactoryImpl.java:397)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:529)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Invalid class loader hierarchy.  You have more than one version of 'org.apache.commons.logging.Log' visible, which is not allowed.
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getLogConstructor(LogFactoryImpl.java:385)
        ... 32 more
Aug 6, 2013 7:55:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
```

Answer (score 0):

Liferay contains axis.jar and makes use of it. If you put it onto the global classpath so that yours gets precedence to the one that Liferay has been delivered/tested with, odds are that it doesn't work. Without further analysis, I'd say that there's a good chance that this is the case.

You can test it by removing it. I'm not aware of the steps I'd recommend to upgrade axis in Liferay. As Liferay does not contain the latest version, I assume that it's not trivial to update, otherwise it probably would have been done already.

Does it work when you deploy axis.jar to your webapp's `WEB-INF/lib` directory?